# TFS 2012 with azure

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am new to TFS, we have the below requirement. 
We need to create simple dot net application which need to be checked in TFS 2012 then we need to build the solution in the TFS and place it in X location (on local machine). and in post build script we need to run the powershell command which upload the files to cloud.

We have written the poowershell command but our concern is how to write build script which will call this powershell script to upload the complied files from local machine to cloud

Comment: This question is pretty loaded, there are a lot of considerations and things required to do. You'll need a build definition/template to start, which you can setup to trigger the script. check out: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-14-Execute-a-PowerShell-script.aspx

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like Release Management for VS to handle your deployments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio Online - Getting Started](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/overview-of-get-started-tasks-vs)

Best place to get you started with Visual Studio Online basics and specifically for a [Build](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/build-your-apps-vs)